# Why does Rademacher Complexity fail for the normal linear regression without a regularization

Tags: machine-learning

For the simple linear regression, assuming i.i.d. Gaussian noise with variance $\sigma^2$, we have $\hat w = (X^TX)^{-1}XY$ and $Var(\hat w) = \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1} = O(\frac{\sigma^2d}{n})$. With high probability, we can bound $\|\hat w - w \|_2$ with $O(\frac{\sigma\sqrt{d}}{\sqrt{n}})$. Then clearly we can give a generalization bound for the estimator $\hat w$ (assuming a bound on $\|x\|_2$).

The above analysis does not assume $\|w\|_2 \leq W$, while all of the Rademacher complexity bound for linear class assume that $\|w\|_2 \leq W$ and $\|x\|_2 \leq X$. It seems to me that with an unbounded function class, the generalization bound with Rad Complexity would fail.

My question is why Rad Complexity is not tight in this setting.